# Bluetooth Code Help

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, connectivity

On the Android developers website, there is code regarding Android Bluetooth connectivity and such. I am very new to Android, and hence can't even follow a simple tutorial. There is a certain section of code

```
BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

Where does this line belong? Does it belong in the main activity or a new, separate activity?

Comment: Perhaps you should start with a simple Java tutorial and then work your way up to Bluetooth as you go?

Comment: I don't have enough time-i got deadlines

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that, but honestly you're going to end up with a lot more problems like the one above if you rush through it without understanding what you're doing. It's a classic case of "do it right the first time." Just my $0.02 obviously.

Comment: coudl you recomend a quick java tutorial that won't take up too much of my time

Comment: I would look through the Hello, World program if you haven't already (http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html) and I would also look at something like this: http://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/~matloff/Java/JavaIntro.html

Comment: There is absolutely no quick way. If you 'got deadlines', pay someone to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BluetoothAdapter myBluetooth = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

belongs in `main()`.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a book called "Sam's teach yourself Java in 24hrs".